# PHP auto complete with mysql multi fields

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, autocomplete

database name "customdata"

```
jobNo CustomerName Country     Tel    Item
1      John        USA         045     Mouse
2      Tony        Australia   054     laptop
3      Karuma      India       548     keyboard
4      Anton       Canada      854     Pen
5      Lusinda     Italy       758     Book
```

Don't care about the database data.

I want add a one text field in php script. when  type "I" it should automatically complete 
dropdown list box like below

```
2,Tony,Australia,054,Laptop
3,Kumara,India,548,keyboard
5,Lusinda,Italy,758,book
```

all rows which include with "I" letter.

In next step "In"

```
3,Kumara,India,548,keyboard
```

will remain and others will goes out.

I can try to autocomplete with jquery.
Some one please help me to select data from table and add into array

Comment: shouldn't In will also give Id=5 data as In in there in name Lusinda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this??

### For 'i'

```
SELECT * 
FROM customdata
WHERE CONCAT(CustomerName, ' ', Country,' ',Item) like '%i%';
```

### For 'in'

```
SELECT *
FROM customdata
WHERE CONCAT(CustomerName, ' ', Country,' ',Item) like '%In%';
```

You just need to do changes in `like '%in%'`

If you want ***case-sensitive*** search, use **BINARY** after `WHERE` statement.

```
SELECT *
FROM customdata
WHERE BINARY CONCAT(CustomerName, ' ', Country,' ',Item) like '%In%';
```

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/55cf9/5)

***NOTE :*** When you type `in`, you will get `id=5` data aslo with `id=3` as `in` is present
 in `CustomerName` Lus **in** da.

### Update 1

In PHP code will be

```
$mySearch = $_POST['mySearchHTMLVariable'];

$query="SELECT * 
        FROM customdata
        WHERE CONCAT(CustomerName, ' ', Country,' ',Item) like '%$mySearch%'";
```

Please do changes as per your requirement.

Comment: Yes friend your are right.I didn't notice about Lus in da. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$searchVar = $_POST['searchVar'];

$search = "Select `jobNo`, `CustomerName`, `Country`, `Tel`, `Item`
    FROM `customdata` c
    WHERE
    `c`.`CustomerName` LIKE '%$searchVar%' OR
    `c`.`Country` LIKE '%$searchVar%' OR
    `c`.`Item` LIKE '%$searchVar%'";
```